# Transfering shapefiles from ArcMap to ArcPad makes all form fields required

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, arcpad

I've figured out how to create shapefiles in the field and record data.  Sometimes I merge these shapefiles in ArcMap and then transfer them to the GPS device in ArcPad using Get Data for ArcPad.  When I do this, every single field in the data collection screen is now Required, which is just unworkable.  Things like FID, Shape, Latitude, Longitude, y_proj, x_proj, and time (from my most recent example) were carried over from merging shapefiles created on different devices and are now all Required despite being fields created and filled by the devices not the users.  I can delete unwanted fields in the Merge process but there are sonme we may want the data from so I didn't delete them.  How do I stop fields from being Required in this process?  The same thing happens when I create or edit a form in ArcPad Studio and then transfer it.

Answer (score 1):

This is an old question, but: you can't. Shape file fields are not nullable. So either use check in/check out through the AP Data Manager to use a file geodatabase or just type blanks or 1s into the fields you don't have values for.